# google-colaboratory Linter does not work correctly with dynamically imported modules

Tags: google-colaboratory, syntax-highlighting

When importing modules dynamically in Google Colab, the imported module and also the autocompletion work, but the Linter flags the imported module as an error, in this case, `"np" is not defined(reportUndefinedVariable)`.

[image: ColabLinter_ImportLibrary]

The cell using the imported module is flagged on the right and `np` is underlined by the Linter. [Try this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z5y1_n7odHSJ71z4VvQmgcVcjojQLCCD?usp=sharing).

How to make the dynamically imported module to be recognized by the Google Colab Linter?

```
# run this code in Google colab

import sys, importlib

module = ['numpy', 'np']
imported_module = importlib.import_module(module[0])
globals()[module[1]] = imported_module
sys.modules[module[0]] = imported_module

np.pi  # the Linter will flag this line and underline `np`
```